# How to store output to a variable using Execute Javascript new Date().toLocaleDateString() in Robot Framework?

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I am using Robot Framework and I want to capture the date that is generated by this method:

```
Execute Javascript  new Date().toLocaleDateString()
```

If I do something like the below the trace log file reflects `${result} = none`. I expect the output to be `${result} = current date`

```
${result} = Execute JavaScript  Date().toLocaleDateString()
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing the `return` function.

```
${result}=    Execute JavaScript    ldate = Date().toLocaleString();    return ldate;
```

EDIT: Changed code to return an object.

Comment: When I change to add return, I receive the error

**Error Message:**
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Date(...).toLocaleDateString is not a function

Comment: @BWW I have edited my answer, with working code.